# Java fill an array with random with random numbers

Tags: java

I have a homework assignment where a user must input the size of an array and then the array must be filled with random values. I am having issues filling the array with something that isn't garbage values. I am sure there are other issues with my code as well but this is the biggest issue I'm currently trying to solve. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class rotateArray1
{
    public static int randomFill()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randomInt = rand.nextInt();
        return randomInt;
    }
    void leftRotate(int arr[], int d, int n)
    {
        int i;
        for(i=0; i < d; i++)
            leftRotateByOne(arr, n);
    }

    void leftRotateByOne(int arr[], int n)
    {
        int i,temp;
        temp = arr[0];
        for(i=0; i < n -1; i++)
            arr[i] = arr[i+1];
        arr[i] = temp;
    }

    void printArray(int arr[],int size)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i<size;i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+ "");
    }
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {

         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter size of array");
         int x= input.nextInt();
         int[] arr = new int[x];

         for(int i = 0; i<x; i++){
             arr[i] = randomFill();
         }


         rotateArray rotate = new rotateArray();
         rotate.leftRotate(arr, 2, x);
         rotate.printArray(arr, x);
         System.exit(0);

     }

  }
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? What is a "garbage value"?

Comment: You don't need `randomFill` just to wrap one line: `randomValue = rand.nextInt();`. Do not declare a new `Random` for every random value because that reduces the apparent randomness. The lifetime of a `Random` should be from before the first random value to after the last one. Don't declare the loop variable in `printArray` outside the loop. Don't use string concatenation for the argument to a `PrintStream#print` call just to get `String.valueOf`. Use braces around `if` and loop bodies, always. Fix your indentation. Don't put implementation in variable or method names.

Comment: What do you mean by "garbage values"? Be specific - what values did you expect to get, and what did you get instead?

Answer (score 0):

Just pass a reference to the array to randomFill and do it in one shot. That helps the code in main() read easier and uses one instance of a Random which is probably more what you want as was pointed out.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String... args) {

        int[] array = new int[10];

        randomFill(array);

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){
            System.out.println("array["+i+"] = "+array[i]);
        }
    }

    static void randomFill(int[] array)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){
            array[i] = rand.nextInt();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
array[0] = 431970257
array[1] = 9846759
array[2] = 1919609165
array[3] = -544686432
array[4] = 655372436
array[5] = -331654257
array[6] = -1187729012
array[7] = 1378209257
array[8] = -1225327561
array[9] = 1887304192
```